# Newer versions of traceroute have limited functionality

Tags: networking, 17.04, ip, traceroute

Running traceroute 1.9.4 on 8.8.8.8 shows

```
traceroute -m 30 -q 1 -w 3 -A 8.8.8.8
traceroute: invalid option -- 'A'
Try 'traceroute --help' or 'traceroute --usage' for more information.
```

However the same command from the stanford website shows a lot more information http://www-wanmon.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/nph-traceroute.pl

```
Executing exec(traceroute -m 30 -q 1 -w 3 -A 1.1.1.1)
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 140 byte packets
 1  rtr-servcore1-serv01-webserv.slac.stanford.edu (134.79.197.130) [AS3671]  0.725 ms
 2  rtr-core2-p2p-serv01-02.slac.stanford.edu (134.79.253.253) [AS3671]  0.665 ms
 3  rtr-fwcore2-trust-p2p-core2.slac.stanford.edu (134.79.254.146) [AS3671]  1.444 ms
 4  rtr-core1-p2p-fwcore1-untrust.slac.stanford.edu (134.79.254.137) [AS3671]  1.402 ms
 5  *
 6  sunncr5-ip-c-slac.slac.stanford.edu (192.68.191.233) [AS3671]  2.225 ms
 7  eqxsjcr5-ip-a-sunncr5.es.net (134.55.38.146) [AS293]  2.215 ms
 8  198.129.44.54 (198.129.44.54) [AS292]  2.179 ms
 9  if-ae-1-2.tcore1.SQN-San-Jose.as6453.net (63.243.205.1) [AS6453]  252.809 ms
10  if-ae-12-2.tcore1.NTO-New-York.as6453.net (63.243.128.28) [AS6453]  252.866 ms
11  if-ae-7-2.tcore1.N0V-New-York.as6453.net (63.243.128.26) [AS6453]  252.106 ms
12  if-ae-2-2.tcore2.N0V-New-York.as6453.net (216.6.90.22) [AS6453]  251.617 ms
13  if-ae-4-2.tcore2.L78-London.as6453.net (80.231.131.157) [AS6453]  252.372 ms
14  if-ae-9-2.tcore2.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net (80.231.200.13) [AS6453]  248.352 ms
15  if-ae-2-2.tcore1.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net (80.231.217.1) [AS6453]  161.635 ms
16  if-ge-2-0-0.core1.N71-Fujairah.as6453.net (195.219.174.26) [AS6453]  252.793 ms
17  195.219.174.18 (195.219.174.18) [AS6453]  301.176 ms
```

Is it that older versions of traceroute had more functionality?
I'm running traceroute on Ubuntu 17.04 installed from the inetutils package.

How do I get the actually useful version of traceroute?

I would like to especially be able to get an ip address provider's AS number

**EDIT:**

Here's `Usage` from my local install

```
jonathan@ubuntu ~> traceroute --usage
Usage: traceroute [-I?V] [-f NUM] [-g GATES] [-m NUM] [-M METHOD] [-p PORT]
            [-q NUM] [-t NUM] [-w NUM] [--first-hop=NUM] [--gateways=GATES]
            [--icmp] [--max-hop=NUM] [--type=METHOD] [--port=PORT]
            [--tries=NUM] [--resolve-hostnames] [--tos=NUM] [--wait=NUM]
            [--help] [--usage] [--version] HOST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`traceroute` has a -A option in Ubuntu. The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/traceroute.db.1.html) for traceroute 17.04 says:

```
 SYNOPSIS

   traceroute [-46dFITUnreAV] [-f first_ttl] [-g gate,...]
           [-i device] [-m max_ttl] [-p port] [-s src_addr]
           [-q nqueries] [-N squeries] [-t tos]
           [-l flow_label] [-w waittime] [-z sendwait] [-UL] [-D]
           [-P proto] [--sport=port] [-M method] [-O mod_options]
           [--mtu] [--back]
           host [packet_len]
   traceroute6  [options]
   tcptraceroute  [options]
   lft  [options]
```

and

```
  -A     Perform AS path lookups in routing registries and print  results
          directly after the corresponding addresses.
```

It would be pretty odd to remove functionality from commands.

Make sure you TYPE it and do not copy/paste from the web. The - might not be a -.

---

My system (17.04) shows this:

```
~$ traceroute -A 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
...
 5  te0-0-0-1-tc1-br1.router.nl.clara.net (212.61.142.218) [AS8426]  8.755 ms  9.239 ms  9.588 ms
 6  core2.ams.net.google.com (80.249.209.100) [AS1200]  10.104 ms  4.409 ms  5.527 ms
```

So it is the normal one. I removed the first 4 due to the nameservers.

Comment: `jonathan@ubuntu ~> traceroute -A 8.8.8.8
traceroute: invalid option -- 'A'
Try 'traceroute --help' or 'traceroute --usage' for more information.
jonathan@ubuntu ~> traceroute -A 8.8.8.8
traceroute: invalid option -- 'A'
Try 'traceroute --help' or 'traceroute --usage' for more information.
`
Both typing it and copy pasting it I get the error above.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question, I really don't have the -A option

Comment: What is inetutiks? AFAIK you install traceroute with apt install traceroute

Comment: I go misleading installation instructions, installed `inetutils-traceroute`

Comment: ah good you got this solved :-)